# For a Standard Visitor visa, what documentation can I submit as proof of accommodation if I am staying at a friend's house?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

My friend, a British citizen, owns the house which means he doesn't rent. However, when I was reading the **visitor: supporting documents guide** on page 8 of 8 (https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf), I realize that council tax and utility bills are also on the list of documents that we should not provide unless otherwise requested. I am planning on attaching his bank statement that contains the address of the house written on it.

But still, what document do I need to show for the proof of accommodation?

On a different note, I found this document (https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/270197/sup-docs-settlement.pdf) and on reading page 3 of 4 under accommodation details, it includes council tax and utility bills as necessary documents.

How come it seems contradicting or am I miss-reading something?

The form might be old or out of date, but I just want to confirm and be on the safe side.

If I include my friend's bank statement, with address written on it, what more should I include to show proof of address or accommodation?

Also regarding the question  **Do  you  have  savings,  property  or  other  income,  for  example, from stocks and shares?**
In regards to savings, if I have only one current account of which I use for day to day staff, but of course there is sufficient funds for everything - both UK trip and coming back and all.

Is my bank balance the savings amount or do they want to see a real savings bank account where you mainly deposit and deposit only?

It seems to me as if some of these questions are open to more than one interpretation.

Comment: he owns the house, so doesn't need anyone's permission

Comment: You still need to _document_ that he owns the house (and so doesn't need a landlord's permission to board guests).

Comment: which document is this then?

Comment: Gayot's suggestion of a certified copy of the deed sounds like it'll be the most foolproof. I don't know if there's a more lightweight option that will work in the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your wires crossed...

You suspect there is a contradiction between two documents you found on the net. The first document is targeted towards visitors, and the second is targeted towards people getting married and coming to the UK to live with their spouse. Different topology, different applications, different everything. It's great to read the guidance, and the one that applies to you is the *Visitor Supporting Documents*.

> On overall, If I include my friend's bank statement- with address
>   written on it, what more should i include to show proof of address or
>   accommodation?

You should include your friends attestation that he will meet you at the airport and be present in the UK during your *entire* visit along with a certified copy of his house deed.  As "best practices" you should also include a copy of the portrait page of his passport.

> Also regarding the question Do you have savings, property or other
>   income, for example, from stocks and shares?

Based upon what you wrote: that you have a single current account and no other financial reserved, you would answer 'no' to this question. There is no requirement that a person have savings or property, but they need to know in order to establish the strength of your ties to your country.

> It seems to me as if some of these questions are open to more than one
>   interpretation.

The rules are vague by design and intent. Both sides of the fence (i.e., the policy side and the advocacy side) agree  that it's better that way.

---

Note: Questions about spouse visas are handled at [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a letter or note from your friend stating that he is willing to accommodate you - a bank statement is not proof that he is accommodating you.

The letter must contain his information (data that proves he is legally staying in the UK); affirmation that he is willing to accommodate you for the dates of your travel; confirmation of ownership of the property.

In addition, I would personally also state his relationship with you - for example, he's a friend or ex-colleague / classmate. This is because if you are visiting a family relative, it requires different kinds of scrutiny form the officers.

Your current account is not the savings account. What is meant here is that you have another *separate* account from your current account where you receive your salary/remuneration/income which can constitute as a form of income or funds that are available to you.

In your case, you would say No since you only have one account.

Comment: I already have that letter

Comment: Is Accommodation letter, and bank statement enough then?

Comment: @Gayot-Fow is the right person for this; but I believe the letter needs to accompany information about your friend (they passport, proof of residency/legality etc. etc.)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, you're doing fine, just add that comment to your answer and it will be a great answer.